# Preload for script and css with file build in Nextjs

Tags: reactjs, performance, next.js, pagespeed-insights, gtmetrix

I have question and still not found the solution for apply preload css and js when run

```
yarn build ; yarn start
```

I have found this in website https://vercel.com/ and want apply that in my website use nextJs version **12.3.1**

[image]

Currently my script and css after build have link with rel prefetch and performance in gtmetrix is not good.

[image]

gtmetrix score i got

[image]

Thanks for read and feel free to comment solution.